# Retrieveing data from a MongoDB database in a javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to get them to show up in an autocomplete but I seem to have an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='" error.

I apologize if you did it wrong, I'm a JavaScript noob.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
  const uri = "mongodb+srv://test:Com.2020@cluster0.n2hnd.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
  const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  });
  client.connect(err => {
    const collection = client.db("test").collection("sephora_backup3");
    var perfumes = collection.find({});
    client.close();
  });
  $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: perfumes,
    minLength: 0
  }).focus(function() {
    /* Muestra todas las opciones al enfocar el input */
    $(this).autocomplete('search', $(this).val())
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="recommendations">
  <!-- <div class="login-page"> -->
  <div class="form">
    <form class="form" action="{% url 'similar_results' %}" method="get" autocomplete="off">
      <input id="autocomplete" type="text" placeholder="Perfume name...">
      <input id="perfumename" type="submit" value="Find Similar Perfumes" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- jQuery-UI CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" />
  <!-- jQuery-Min JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- jQuery-UI JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think maybe the Error is caused by the missing variable name in your code ;)

```
client.connect(err => {
  ....
  ....
  var = collection.find({}); // there is no variable name after the keyword "var"
  ....
  ....  
});
```

Comment: this kind of errors happens with me all the time :)